# Formatting Decimal places in Access/MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a database which is an access frontend with a  MySQL backend.
In MySQL I have a table with a field set at 3 decimal places (10, 3), however does anyone know how I can display this field as 1 decimal place only in the fronend access, without altering the MySQL table formatting?

Answer (score 3):

In the TextBox of your Access form you should set the Format property to a numeric format and the property Decimal Places to 1. You will find these properties in the Format tabs of the property editor.